# numpy shape inconsistent with array structure

Tags: arrays, list, numpy, object, shapes

I am going mad over this thing.

I have 2 lists

```
A = [ [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]], [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]]
B = [ [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]], [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]]
```

When I call the shape of A and B as numpy array I get this:

```
In [33]: np.asarray(A).shape
Out[33]: (2, 3, 3)

In [31]: np.asarray(B).shape
Out[31]: (2,)
```

How do I shape `A` in the same way as `B`, that is `(2,)`?

I think I understand why it's happening but I don't know how to prevent this to happening.
Anyone any help/idea please?

thanks!

Comment: tell us why it's happening.  And show `B`, not just its shape

Comment: The (2,3,3) shape is consistent with the list nesting.  Count the brackets!  The spaces don't mean think.  Look at the display of `A` and of [33].

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 lists:

```
In [232]: A
Out[232]: [[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]]
In [233]: B
Out[233]: [[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]]
```

Now, explain why the `B` result is better than the `A` one?

```
In [234]: np.array(A)
Out[234]: 
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]]])

In [235]: np.array(B)
<ipython-input-235-c938532b77c1>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  np.array(B)
Out[235]: 
array([list([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]),
       list([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, thanks for replying. I want to clarify that I don't think it's "better". I just need that shape format because in the model I am using all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions (i.e., shape (2,)). It's ok that all the elements of the A array have the same shape, however, I need that main array object to be read as a 1D shape not 3D. That's all I need, of course if it's possible.